# `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` in laravel 8

Tags: php

I use Laravel 8 to export PDFs with dompdf. But when I send a request I get an error like "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

[image]

I tried increasing memory in php.ini of `shivammathur/8.0` but it did not work.

```
<form id="getPDF" method="GET" action="/sell/export-pdf">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="filterJson" v-model="filterJson">
 </form>
```

Comment: Please update your question with the controller method code that you have tried so far and any other useful information